# The R dplyr function arrange(ymd(col)) is not working

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

```
df<-data.frame(record_id=1:5,group=c('A','B','C','D','E'),
    date_start=c('Apr-22','Aug-21','Jan-22','Feb-22','Dec-21'))
```

This is the code I'm attempting to use to order my column by chronological date vs alphabetically.

```
arrange(ymd(date_start))
```

I feel like I've tried reformatting/reclassing in every known way, and it's still either giving an error or not sorting chronologically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format should be `myd` as it is in the order of month, year, and (day) was not there, so use `truncated = 1`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
    arrange(myd(date_start, truncated = 1))
```

Or can also use `my` as there is missing 'day'

```
df %>% 
   arrange(my(date_start))
```

-output

```
  record_id group date_start
1         2     B     Aug-21
2         5     E     Dec-21
3         3     C     Jan-22
4         4     D     Feb-22
5         1     A     Apr-22
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(date_start1 = myd(paste0(date_start,"-01")))
```

```
  record_id group date_start
1         2     B     Aug-21
2         5     E     Dec-21
3         3     C     Jan-22
4         4     D     Feb-22
5         1     A     Apr-22
```