# Why and how can arrange do the same as a combination of mutate, arrange and select in one line?

Tags: r, dplyr

This question arose by working on this [The R dplyr function arrange(ymd(col)) is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73143337/the-r-dplyr-function-arrangeymdcol-is-not-working/73143427#73143427)

**We have this data frame:**

```
df <- structure(list(record_id = 1:5, group = c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
"E"), date_start = c("Apr-22", "Aug-21", "Jan-22", "Feb-22", 
"Dec-21")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

  record_id group date_start
1         1     A     Apr-22
2         2     B     Aug-21
3         3     C     Jan-22
4         4     D     Feb-22
5         5     E     Dec-21
```

**We would like to sort date_start:**

**My first approach:** worked

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  mutate(date_start1 = myd(paste0(date_start,"-01"))) %>% 
  arrange(date_start1) %>% 
  select(-date_start1)

  record_id group date_start
1         2     B     Aug-21
2         5     E     Dec-21
3         3     C     Jan-22
4         4     D     Feb-22
5         1     A     Apr-22
```

**Then I tried this** and it also worked

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  arrange(date_start1 = myd(paste0(date_start,"-01")))

  record_id group date_start
1         2     B     Aug-21
2         5     E     Dec-21
3         3     C     Jan-22
4         4     D     Feb-22
5         1     A     Apr-22
```

I would like to understand how **one `arrange`** can do the same as a **combination of `mutate`, `arrange` and `select`**

Comment: If you look at the last one, `arrange` doesn't create a new column, `date_start1` in the dataset ie. `... - <data-masking> Variables, or functions of variables.`

Comment: That's a cool trick! It seems like `arrange` is invisibly creating a temporary `date_start1` to sort off of and then removing it. Can't find that documented anywhere.

Comment: @akrun Yes I see. but this is kind of very new. So arrange does mutate with .keep="unused"?

Comment: arrange.data.frame calls `dplyr:::arrange_rows` and if you check it is doing a loop with `map2` (`transmute` is also used)

Comment: See [source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/HEAD/R/arrange.R)

Comment: I did not know this but I think it makes more sense if you think about it without the assignment in the arrange statement, i.e. `arrange(myd(paste0(date_start,"-01")))`. I wouldn't use it though - fewer keystrokes but makes the code less clear.

Comment: This question feels a bit off-topic to me. (Though I'll also comment that, inspired by SQL, this behavior does not feel unexpected. In SQL there's lots of flexibility for what you can put in an `ORDER BY` clause. `mtcars %>% arrange(runif(n()))` is exactly how I'd expect to implement a "shuffle" of `mtcars`.)

Comment: Whether or not this behavior is intuitive based on other languages, this functionality is not clearly documented in the help and even looking through the source code it's pretty cryptic to me how it works so I think there's value in keeping the question open for someone to give a full explanation.

Comment: @DanAdams Sorry, I didn't mean to tie my "intuitiveness" and my "off-topic" thoughts together. I think it's off-topic because *"How does this [long, complicated] function [from popular package] work"* seems off-topic to me for not being specific enough. The code is available and linked, but it's 200+ lines of code. I'm just having trouble imagining any suitably happy medium between akrun's comment (*"`map2` and `transmute`"*) and a heavily annotated walk through of the source code--which seems too long for this medium. Though maybe someone will prove me wrong and deliver...

Comment: @SamR as i explain in my answer, the best way to think of it is that you are assigning values to an object to be sorted on -- not assigning to a column in the object passed to arrange!  So long as it produces a vector whose elements can be sorted, it works.

Comment: And they're equivalent because `arrange` doesn't care if that vector has a name?

Comment: @SamR it's the same for `sort()`: `sort(10:1); foo <- 10:1 ; sort(foo) ; df = data.frame(x = 10:1); sort(df$x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What the code is **not** doing

The output of `arrange()` is perhaps surprising because you think it is doing the following:

Everything to the right of the `=` is just a function to create a vector.

```r
time_col <- df$date_start %>% 
  paste0(.,"-01") %>%
  myd() %>%
  print()
#> [1] "2022-04-01" "2021-08-01" "2022-01-01" "2022-02-01" "2021-12-01"
```

The `=` of course is assignment to a new column :

```r
  df <- df %>%
  mutate(date_start1 = time_col) %>%
    print()
#>   record_id group date_start date_start1
#> 1         1     A     Apr-22  2022-04-01
#> 2         2     B     Aug-21  2021-08-01
#> 3         3     C     Jan-22  2022-01-01
#> 4         4     D     Feb-22  2022-02-01
#> 5         5     E     Dec-21  2021-12-01
```

You're then sorting on that variable:

```
  df %>% arrange(date_start1)
#>   record_id group date_start date_start1
#> 1         2     B     Aug-21  2021-08-01
#> 2         5     E     Dec-21  2021-12-01
#> 3         3     C     Jan-22  2022-01-01
#> 4         4     D     Feb-22  2022-02-01
#> 5         1     A     Apr-22  2022-04-01
```

## What the code **is** doing

If you look at the output, the code is not actually doing what is shown previously and then removing a column. It is missing the new column `date_start1` without us even needing to remove it manually:

```r
  df %>% 
    arrange(date_start1 = myd(paste0(date_start,"-01")))
#>   record_id group date_start
#> 1         2     B     Aug-21
#> 2         5     E     Dec-21
#> 3         3     C     Jan-22
#> 4         4     D     Feb-22
#> 5         1     A     Apr-22
```

The key then is to understand that **you are not creating a new variable that is added to the `data.frame`, sorting on it, then removing it**. Rather, you are passing a set of values (one per row) on which to sort.

## Why this is possible

This is permitted because you can pass any arbitrary vector that may (not) be a function of the variables in the data. As noted in the documentation for `arrange()`, the second argument is:

> Variables, or functions of variables. Use desc() to sort a variable in descending order.

All you are doing is passing a function of variables! This is why you can also do:

```r
  df %>% 
    arrange(1:nrow(df) + record_id)
  #>   record_id group date_start
  #> 1         1     A     Apr-22
  #> 2         2     B     Aug-21
  #> 3         3     C     Jan-22
  #> 4         4     D     Feb-22
  #> 5         5     E     Dec-21
```